# Where is the torus primitive in geometry nodes?

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to add a torus primitive object in geometry nodes to use as an instance input, but Blender doesn't seem to have one within the geometry nodes context.  Is there a way to input a torus mesh procedurally within geometry nodes instead of calling a static outside object? I've searched around online and nobody seems to be asking about this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can add a torus by using two `Curve Circle` nodes and combining them with a `Curve to Mesh` node. The first circle is plugged into the *Curve* input and controls the major radius and segments (*Resolution*). The second circle is plugged into the *Profile Curve* input and controls the minor radius and segments (*Resolution*):

[image]

Comment: This may be a small and relatively simple answer, but you've taken just that little bit of extra time to label everything and describe usage. Appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks Robin. Less than a day later. This is already the top online search result when searching for "blender geometry nodes where is the torus" on google. The view count here should indicate how many people had trouble figuring it out without help. Maybe the Blender team should just add the torus primitive directly in so its easier to find.